# Service to service authentication is not allowed using forge Autodesk

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-construction-cloud

In 'Autodesk Construction Cloud APIs' I try to use GET method for projects/{projectId}/issues.
This is the documentation for the API: [Get issues API Link](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/issues-issues-GET/)

I am using Postman and for other API's it works without problems, but for some reason for this API I got the following error:

image of the error:
[image]

I know my ProjectId and Token are fine. I am wondering if it has to do with some access the admin must to give me.

best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your access token is 2-legged. Instead, you will need to use a 3-legged one since its `Authentication Context` is `user context required`.

See:

- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/basics/
- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/
- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token-implicit/